# jQuery('#news-ticker').cycle is not a function

Tags: plugins, jquery

I am using the news Ticker plugin 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/news-ticker
It shows an error jQuery('#news-ticker').cycle is not a function. In IE It throws an error Dom Element Does not Exist!. How to resolve this error.

Thanks.

Comment: By contacting the author and telling him.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the cycle.js file is included and should be above this code in the

```
jQuery('#news-ticker').cycle
```

also make sure jquery library is included once, some of the plugins include its separate jquery file which creates such conflicts.

Regards.

Comment: hi my issue resolved, its an jquery conflict issue.